# Combine image and text in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheets it is possible to show an image in a cell using the formula `=image('http://www.example.com/path/to/image.ext', 3)` (where `3` means to use the images' original size).

I would like to include some text in the same cell as the image. I have tried to use `concat` but that results in `#ERROR`.

```
=concat(image(URL,MODE), 'string')
```

In the same cell, how do I combine an image and text at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way, that I am aware of, to combine an image and some text in the same cell using the `image` function.

The `concat` method [concatenates strings, only](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592).

The only "workaround" I can think of, is inserting the image using *Insert → Image*, and positioning the image next to a text cell. But this is obviously not a perfect solution in any way.

Answer (score -1):

It works if you insert the image using the over the cell option.  You then have to resize and position the image so that it fits in the cell.